# complex dependencies in mysql, how to

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I start with an example.
MySQL database, 3 tables:

```
items: id; lots of info about this item
container: id; name
items_container: id; item_id; container_id; count
```

So this is the basic structure, first two tables are the items and containers, the third is the table which basically stores how many items are in the container, one type of item can be in many different containers.

What I need to do:
Transactions: add, remove, move items between containers

All of them should be stored with other information about the transaction. After user adds a transaction of addition of some items to a container it should be stored, as user could delete the transaction later and items should be removed. Same goes with removal - if we add a transaction of removal with 5 items with id 3 to a container with id 2, later delete it, the items should back. This is fairly simple, but the "moving" transactions get just more complex and I don't know what is the right way to do this, simply store item id and count?

May some of you already had to develop some system similar to this one and could suggest some better solutions to this? Performance is nice, but it is not so critical here as reliability is. The one last thing is that a transaction can have multiple items (in fact it usually will have multiple different items to manage).

Thank you in advance, I hope I explained what I want to achieve.

Comment: Cannot we normalize the database this way -

1. item - id; CONTAINER_ID; field1; field2; .... field n;
2. container - id; field1; field 2; ..... field n;

**?**

Plus use on delete cascade and on update cascade;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recomendation would be to

- create a transactions table with transaction_id auto_increment,container_id_add, container_id_sub,item_id, count, status=0 and whatever you want (username, timestamp, ...)
- Make your application submit transactions by writing to this table
- Create insert trigger on this table, that fulfills or fails the transaction, writing the result to status
- Make your application check the result of the transaction

Why this?

- the structure container_id_add, container_id_sub,item_id, count allows for addition (container_id_sub=invalid, e.g. -1, 0, NULL), removal (container_id_add invalid) or move
- You can easily wrap that into stored procedures if you want, or you can access the table, whatever fits your usage pattern
- The transactions table is a perfect changelog